# Wordpress meta_query datetime operations

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to load posts (product type) of all the products that have custom-field ('date_flag'), if the time that stored on this custom field is before more than 4 hours (if 4 hours passed from the date that stored on this custom field).

For example, if 'date_flag' is 2020-11-12 10:00:00 and now its 2020-11-12 14:30:00 then give me this post.

```
$args= array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'meta_query' => array( 
    array(
    'key' => 'date_flag',
    'value' => what-to-do-here
    'compare' => what-to-do-here
   ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggested reading up more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/

```
// compare against now
array(
  'key' => 'date_flag', // field to check
  'value' => date("Y-m-d"), // today's date 
  'compare' => '<=', // your compare operator
  'type' => 'DATE' // tell WP we're working with date
  )
)

// compare against now + 4 hours
array(
  'key' => 'date_flag', // field to check
  'value' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+4 hours')), 
  'compare' => '<=', // your compare operator
  'type' => 'DATE' // tell WP we're working with date
  )
)

// compare against some other date + 4 hours
$other_date = '2020-11-12 00:00:00';
$compare_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+4 hours', strtotime($other_date));
array(
  'key' => 'date_flag', // field to check
  'value' => $compare_date, 
  'compare' => '<=', // your compare operator
  'type' => 'DATE' // tell WP we're working with date
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. But... your answer explain how to compare to today, i want to check if the 'date_flag' is 4 hours from other date.

Comment: so compare against "now" plus four hours?  or do you have some "other" that you need to add four hours to?

Comment: Updated to include more examples.

Comment: Thanks. Generally good answer, but for my target its not the correct answer. I want to check if 4 hours passed from 'date_flag'... your solution check if 'date_flag' is after current time+4 ... by this, it will always give the same result.

If 'date_flag' is [2020-11-12 07:00:00] and now its [2020-11-12 11:01:00] = true, 
if 'date_flag' is [2020-11-12 07:00:00] and now its [2020-11-12 10:01:00] = false,